# Having issues with event on click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a button instance named "instructionButton" and I'm trying to trace "Clicked." to the output when it is clicked as a test but I haven' been successful thus far. Is there something I'm missing?

I'm using code in Flash Pro 6

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var clickedVar:String = "Clicked.";
var runVar:String = "mice running...";


trace(runVar);

function instructionOpen(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(clickedVar);
    gotoAndPlay(255);
}

instructionsButton.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, instructionOpen);
```

And of course if there's a more simple way to approach this, all knowledge will be helpful.

Comment: it looks like it should work.  Are you getting any output to the output window?  Or any errors?   Your problem is likely elsewhere.  Post your .fla if you can.  Maybe your instance name has a typo?

Comment: in your description you say the instance name is `instructionButton` and in your code you have `instructionsButton`, note the **s**

Comment: @Ronnie true. Sean Moran If you're wandering whether it's the right way to go, it is. You should add a listener and then handle the event in your handler function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check instance name is provided or not in the property window for the button (click the button and go to menu 'Window->Properties' to open property window)
2. What name is mentioned in the property window for the button, should use the same instance name in action script coding. Ensure the spelling from both script(code) and property window instance name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see anything wrong with your button code, but here's how i do mine in AS3, it may help :) Creating a simple function within the event listener, I use stopPropgation to prevent my button from clicking anything that may be below it in the flash file. ( say you  have two buttons on top of one another, you'll click both instead of one)

```
instructionsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    trace("Clicked.");
    gotoAndPlay(255);
    });
```

This is one button, if you need say fifteen, let me know as I have a code sample I'll give you that i use to create a limitless amount of buttons and eventlistners using switch/case which has been a huge help to me :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way this will not work is if you are not reaching this frame.

Try  add this code on your first frame and tell me if this helping.